# Can i combine Slim Framework with plain PHP

Tags: php

I just started with PHP not too long ago and have done some small projects with just plain PHP + Ajax + html.
I’m more comfortable with procedural code than OOP. I can still use OOP library of Pakagist. But i want to go slow the first time using a framework.

I want to do a serious new project with Slim but in a procedural way.
My ideas:

Only use routing to require a view
My Url: `example.com/?r={child router}&page={view}`

Routing: Only used to require to a child router and forward $parameter.
Template & View: will receive a json result from ajax callback, my app will heavy ajax.

```
$app->get('/}', function() {
    require "index.view";
});
$app->get('/{route}/{page}', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {
    $route = $args['route'] ? $args['route'] : "";
    $page = $args['page'] ? $args['page'] : "";
// I have a folder View contains folder User
    if folder_exists("route/" . $route)
    {
        if file_exists("view/" . $route . "/" . $page . ".php")
        {
            require ("view/" . $route . "/" . $page . ".php");
        } else {
            require ("view/" . $route . "/def_page.php");
        }
    } else {
      header (Location: index.php);
    }
});


// example.com/?r=user&page=register
// will require view/user/register.php

// example.com/?r=admin&page=login
// will require view/admin/login.php
```

And all my logic will be handled through an ajax route like

```
$app->get('/ajax/{route}/{action}', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {
    $route = $args['route'] ? $args['route'] : "";
    $action= $args['action'] ? $args['action'] : "";
// I have a folder View contains folder User
    
        if file_exists("ajax/" . $route . "/" . $page . ".php")
        {
            require ("ajax/" . $route . "/" . $page . ".php");
        } else {
            $result = [
                        'status' => false,
                        'msg' => 'failed'
            ]
            return json_encode($result);
        }
});

// example.com/?r=ajax&action=login
// will require ajax/user/login.php
```

Please help me and let me know if this doesn’t fit in Slim or anything bad.
Thanks for help.

UPDATE:
I used this route library.
It very simple and nice.
Slim 4, he's slim but very complex.

```
<?php
use Core\Libs\View;
use Core\Libs\Config;

$route = new AltoRouter();

$route->map( 'GET', '/', ['route' => 'core', 'page' => 'landing']);

$route->map( 'GET', '/user', ['route' => 'user', 'page' => 'home']);

$route->map( 'GET', '/user/login', ['route' => 'user', 'page' => 'login']);

$match = $route->match();

?>
    Target: <?php var_dump($match['target']); ?><br>
    Params: <?php var_dump($match['params']); ?><br>
    Name:   <?php var_dump($match['name']); ?><br>
<?

if( is_array($match) && isset( $match['target'] ) ) {
    //call_user_func_array( $match['target'], $match['params'] );
    var_dump($match);
} else {
    header( $_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] . ' 404 Not Found');
    echo 'Không tìm thấy trang';
}
```

Comment: Your routing idea is not very good, you should have a clear idea of what you want your back end code to do and have specific routes for specific purposes.  It's worth spending the time to do this now than leave it till later and try and redo it all.  This also allows any front end user to execute any page they want, not particularly secure.

Comment: I'm really not ready for a big framework like Laravel, Yii... and I also feel it's unnecessary
There are 2 reasons:
1. Because I only develop small api apps, only myself, not a team.
2. Well, abstract stuff isn't for me. I will fly 200km/h with plain php or rolling 1m/day with OPP :D
Just funny, I'm still learning OOP PHP while working with plain php & some OOP library. I still want to continue working with plain php until I understand all about OOP php.
I want refactor my application step by step, right now. And not pure OOP :D

Comment: Most of my current apps work this way:
- Start with a Simple mySQL library.
- Views file includes "header.php", "footer.php" and HTML mixed PHP in middles.
- Views will popup modal for CRUD and input.
- Modals do ajax to login_ajax.php, register_ajax.php ( many files xxx_ajax.php @@ )

Comment: Should i combine plain PHP logic with OOP feature of framework?
Có giải pháp đơn giản và hiện đại nào cho tôi không?

Comment: If you don't want to get bogged down with a heavy framework at this stage of your development, can I recommend something like this [No Framework Tutorial](https://github.com/PatrickLouys/no-framework-tutorial)? It will help you to quickly get started with a project while still teaching you some best practices.

Comment: Thank you, I'll dig into it. This is what I need.
And I'm also learning to use Github. So that my code can easily receive the support of the community.